# how to post multiple associative array entries to postman and how to access that in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, rest, api, postman, associative-array

I am new to laravel and also creating restful APIs.

I want to send `array` of `product_id` and `product_amount`. This array can have multiple products entries in it, `array{ product_id: 1 product_amount: 1000 , product_id: 2 product_amount: 5000}` like this. I want to send this associative array to controller via API and in controller I want to access this array with its fields.

I have gone through some online solutions but that not solving my problem. Like for post array by postman:

```
$ass_array = array(
   “product_id” => “1”, 
   “product_amount” => “1000”
);
```

we have to mention

```
 key: array[product_id] , value: 1

key: array[product_amount] , value: 1000
```

In this case if I add another entry its not showing on postman. how can I post multiple entries through associative array to controller?

Also I have checked that we can access array by `dot operator` in controller. But I don't know how I can do this in my case?

Please guide. thanks in advance

Comment: How would you like to send the array to the server? Javascript or what? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I am sending array by postman using post method via API

Answer (score 4):

So first you need to create a new controller by using the `php artisan make:controller` command. In my case I call it `ArrayApiController` (Im sure you will find a better name).

So my command looks like this:

`php artisan make:controller ArrayApiController`

Now you have a new controller to handle your incomming request. After this we have to create a new route to redirect requests to this new controller.

For this we add a new entry into the `api.php` file under `routes/api.php`. I suggest to add api related routes in the `api.php` to keep it clean and organized.

So add this line into the `routes/api.php` file:

```
Route::post('array', 'ArrayApiController@post');
```

You can change the `::post` to your prefered http method and the url (`array` in my case) to whatever you want ([Here are all available http methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)).

So requests to `/api/array` will now be redirected to the `post` function in the `ArrayApiController` we've created earlier.

So now create a new function called `post` in the new controller (`ArrayApiController` in my case):

```
public function post(Request $request)
{
  //
}
```

You can now get submitted data by using `$request->get(NAME_OF_THE_DATA)`. In the next code snippet you can see that I took `products` as name of the products variables I submit with postman.

```
public function post(Request $request)
{
    // get all products
    $products = $request->get('products');
}
```

Now you are able to loop over your products and do whatever you want (In my case just expose it but you could also write those variables in the DB):

```
public function post(Request $request)
{
    // get all products
    $products = $request->get('products');

    // loop through all products
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo $product['product_id'];
        echo $product['product_amount'];
    }
}
```

Now go to postman and create a new request. Change the http method to your entered method in the `api.php` file (In my case I've added `Route::post(..` to the `api.php` file so I have to create a `POST` request). Then add a new header called `Content-Type` and set it to `application-json`. As body you can now send your array as json:

```
{

  // You can call the variable how you want
  "products": [
    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_ammount": 500
    },
    {
        "product_id": 2,
        "product_ammount": 1500
    }
  ]
}
```

Make sure that the content type of your body is json.

Instead of `products` you could take what you want but it has tobe the same as in the `ArrayApiController` in the `$request->get()` statement stated.

If you want to add authentication to the api or more informations about it here is a good link -> [Build RESTful API In Laravel 5.8 Example](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/build-restful-api-in-laravel-58-exampleexample.html).

---

Now how you need to make the postman request:

[image: screenshot; postman header settings]

[image: screenshot; postman body content]

Comment: can you please share screenshot of how did you add that 2 entries `product_id` and `product_amount` in postman?

Comment: Above code giving me error on postman like  "message": "Illegal string offset 'product_id'", Note: I put `1) key: products[product_id] value: 1,2  (2) key: products[product_credit_amount] value: 1000,5000` on postman

Comment: I've added two screenshots. I've made a little mistake in the code for the postman body. The strings need " at the start and the end. I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: I was stuck because I couldn't "see" in my controller the array of objects I was posting from Postman and it was because of the content/type header. Seeing your answer helped me figure it out and, for that, I LOVE YOU! THANK YOU!.

Comment: @clesmalo Glad to hear that my answer could help you! Have a nice day.